# Pasar diferentes valores a un string sin repetir los mismos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito pasarle a las url diferentes valores, como se ve en el ejemplo en primer lugar le paso los valores que contiene dt_3, el problema es que necesito pasarle a todas las url el resto de los valores, o sea dt_7 y dt_31.

Como puedo simplificar el proceso sin tener que estar repitiendo las url para dt_7 y dt_31 y luego todas las url deberian de estar contenidas en una lista, las url no tienen el mismo formato.

Gracias

```
    from datetime import date, timedelta

    dt_3 = date.today() + timedelta(3)
    dt_7 = date.today() + timedelta(7)
    dt_31 = date.today() + timedelta(31)

    Salta_Centro= 'https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear={0}&doFiltering=true \
                    &dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={1}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth={2}&dropFtsInput=salta&dropCountry=Argentina \
                    &dropLongitude=-65.4167&puDay={3}&dropFtsLocationSearch=161&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10 \
                    &dropFtsLocationName=Salta&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&puYear={4}&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput=salta \
                    &ftsLocationName=Salta&ftsSearch=L&location=161&doMonth={5}&reducedCategory=medium&filterAdditionalInfo=&advSearch=&exSuppliers=&ordering=price' \
                    .format(dt_3.year,dt_3.day,date.today().month,date.today().day,date.today().year,dt_3.today().month,).replace(' ','')

    Mendoza_Centro = 'https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear={0}&doFiltering=true \
                    &dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={1}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth={2}&dropFtsInput=Mendonza&dropCountry=Argentina \
                    &dropLongitude=-68.843&puDay={3}&dropFtsLocationSearch=106&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10 \
                    &dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete=Mendoza%2c+Mendoza%2c+Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete=Mendoza%2c+Mendoza%2c+Argentina \
                    &dropFtsLocationName=Mendoza&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&puYear={4}&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput=Mendoza \

                    &ftsLocationName=Mendoza&ftsSearch=L&location=106&doMonth={5}&reducedCategory=medium&filterAdditionalInfo=&advSearch=&exSuppliers=&ordering=price' \
                    .format(dt_3.year,dt_3.day,date.today().month,date.today().day,date.today().year,dt_3.today().month,).replace(' ','')


    Tucuman_Centro = 'https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear={0}&doFiltering=true \
                    &dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={1}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth={2}&dropFtsInput=tucuman&dropCountry=Argentina \
                    &puDay={3}&dropFtsLocationSearch=-1&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10 \
                    &dropFtsLocationName=Tucum%C3%A1n&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&puYear={4}&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput=tucuman \
                    &ftsLocationName=Tucum%C3%A1n&ftsSearch=L&location=-1&doMonth={5}&reducedCategory=medium&filterAdditionalInfo=&advSearch=&exSuppliers=&ordering=price' \
                    .format(dt_3.year,dt_3.day,date.today().month,date.today().day,date.today().year,dt_3.today().month,).replace(' ','')


    buenos_aires = 'https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear={0}&doFiltering=true \
                    &dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={1}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth={2}&dropFtsInput=buenos+aires&dropCountry=Argentina \
                    &dropLongitude=-58.3816&puDay={3}&dropFtsLocationSearch=51&puHour=10&dropFtsEntry=22776&enabler=&distance=10 \
                    &dropFtsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&dropCountryCode=&doMinute=0&countryCode=&puYear={4}&locationName=&puMinute=0&ftsInput=buenos+aires \
                    &ftsLocationName=Buenos+Aires&ftsSearch=L&location=51&doMonth={5}&reducedCategory=medium&filterAdditionalInfo=&advSearch=&exSuppliers=&ordering=price' \
                    .format(dt_3.year,dt_3.day,date.today().month,date.today().day,date.today().year,dt_3.today().month,).replace(' ','')


urlList = [Salta_Centro,Mendoza_Centro,Tucuman_Centro,buenos_aires]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, aunque no es lo que preguntas, cuidado con la cadena que ocupa varias líneas, has hecho lo siguiente (pongo un ejemplo más simplificado):

```
cadena = 'Esto es una cadena larga \
          que ocupa varias lineas'
```

Has incluído un `\` al final de la línea para indicar que continúa por la siguiente, pero no has tenido en cuenta que todos los espacios que hay delante de la palabra "que" también serán parte de una cadena. Esto es:

```
>>> cadena
'Esto es una cadena larga           que ocupa varias lineas'
```

No queremos esto, especialmente en tu caso en que la cadena es una URL, pues estás introduciendo espacios indeseados en la misma.

Para resolver esto conviene recordar un par de trucos:

1. Dos cadenas literales que aparezcan seguidas en el código son concatenadas por python en una sola. Es decir, si haces:

   ```
   prueba = "Esto es una "   "prueba"   "?"
   ```

   será lo mismo que si huberas hecho:

   ```
   prueba = "Esto es una prueba?"
   ```
2. Una expresión entre paréntesis puede partirse en varias líneas sin necesidad de poner `\` al final de cada una.

Juntando ambos trucos, la asignación anterior podía quedar así:

```
cadena = ("Esto es una cadena larga "
          "que ocupa varias lineas")
```

Y ahora sí, vamos con tu pregunta.

La cadena con la URL enorme es bastante repetitiva, pero no es 100% idéntica para todos los casos. He intentado buscar "a ojo" qué partes son iguales y cuáles diferentes, pero al final es bastante complejo y he preferido mostrarte cómo sería el método general, en lugar de tratar de resolverlo para este problema específico.

La idea es tener una cadena "plantilla" que tenga toda la parte común, y que use en cambio *placeholders* como `{1}`, `{2}`, etc en las partes que haya que  sustituir. Como lo que tú has hecho para los datos de la fecha, pero extendiéndolo también a los datos de la ciudad.

Algo así:

```
plantilla = ("https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?"
             "country={pais}&doYear={año}&doFiltering=true"
             "&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay={dia}&searchType=allareasgeosearch&"
             "filterFrom=0&puMonth={mes}&dropFtsInput={input}&"
             "dropCountry={pais}"
             "...")
```

En una lista tendrías una serie de diccionarios con los datos a sustituir en los *placeholders*. Por ejemplo:

```
casos = [
  {  "pais": "Argentina",
     "input": "salta",
     "location": "Salta"},
  {  "pais": "Argentina",
     "input": "mendoza",
     "location": "Mendoza"},
  ]
```

Finalmente un bucle que recorra la lista `casos` puede usar `format` sobre la `plantilla` proporcionando un diccionario con los campos a rellenar. Puedes extender el diccionario que sale de `casos` con los datos de la fecha. Por ejemplo:

```
for datos in casos:
  datos.update({"año": 2018, "mes": 10, "dia": 17})
  print(plantilla.format(**datos))
```

Este código, con la `plantilla` y los datos contenidos en los `casos` que antes puse a modo de ejemplo, imprimiría las siguientes cadenas
(en vez de imprimirlas, naturalmente puedes ir guardándolas en una lista):

```
https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear=2018&doFiltering=true&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay=17&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth=10&dropFtsInput=salta&dropCountry=Argentina...
https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?country=Argentina&doYear=2018&doFiltering=true&dropFtsSearch=L&doDay=17&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&puMonth=10&dropFtsInput=mendoza&dropCountry=Argentina...
```

Como dije, esta no es una solución directa, sino sólo el mecanismo. Tienes que adaptarlo a tu caso con la plantilla correcta y el diccionario de datos apropiado para cada caso.